# How to set fullcalendar view to start 1 week before the current date?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using Vue version of fullcalendar.io (v5) [Resource Timeline View](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view) with a custom view object passed via settings and I can't figure out how to set it up so that the calendar start 1 week before the current date. I've tried initialDate, activeStart, visibleRange options with no luck. It just starts at the beginning of the current month no matter what. Relevant settings code:

```
    views: {
        resourceTimelineThreeMonths: {
            type: 'resourceTimeline',
            duration: { months: 3 },
            activeStart: '2021-03-06',
            initialDate: '2021-03-06',
            // dayCount: 40,
            visibleRange: {
              start: '2021-3-6',
              end: '2021-5-13'
            },
        }
    },
    expandRows: true, 
    plugins: [
      resourceCommonPlugin,
      resourceTimelinePlugin,
      interactionPlugin,
    ],

    schedulerLicenseKey: "GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source",
    initialView: "resourceTimelineThreeMonths"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that if you set the `duration` value using `months` as the denominator, fullCalendar takes this as a sign that you want a month to be the core block of time by which the calendar is set, and that the `initialDate` is simply a date which falls into that period.

If you use a smaller time denomination, then it's more flexible - e.g. using `weeks` will allow it to start at the beginning of the nearest week instead of the beginning of the nearest month. If you use `days` as the denominator then you have even more flexibility.

If you set a `duration` value then `visibleRange` has no effect. `duration` takes precedence over it.

Also, `initialDate` isn't a view-specific option, it must be specified as a global option, rather than within the settings for a particular view, otherwise it has no effect.

So you would end up with settings something like this:

```
views: {
  resourceTimelineThreeMonths: {
    type: "resourceTimeline",
    duration: { weeks: 12 },
  }
},
initialDate: "2021-03-06",
//...etc
```

Demo using `weeks`: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJbqJxZ

Demo using `days`: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/wvoOvpx

Demo using a static `visibleRange`: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/rNWRNJa

---

P.S. There's no such option as `activeStart`, not sure where you got that one from?

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I will give it a try asap! I'm sooo confused with all the options. The activeStart is here fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object but I now realize that's just readonly fields of the View object as it's passed into handlers

Comment: Setting duration to days worked! Did you open an issue with fullcalendar github repo by any chance ? I wonder if it;s a bug or by design

Comment: I didn't open an issue for it no. I would guess maybe it's by design because it seems like there's a pattern, but I don't know for sure. You could open an issue to ask if you wanted. Glad it helped anyway.