Setting scrollbar position on FullCalendar Year Timeline view
Is there a way to automatically adjust the lower scrollbar to represent the current time when the year view is initially loaded? I am working on a project where it would be highly beneficial for the end-users to see the current month positioned in the center of the scrollbar upon opening the year view. This feature would enhance user experience by immediately showing relevant data without requiring manual adjustments.
Unfortunately, I haven’t found any references or guidelines in the available documentation that describe how to implement this feature. I checked the standard settings and properties but didn't see an option that directly controls the scrollbar's initial position based on the current date or time.
Here's an image of the year view setup I'm referring to: year view example. As you can see, the scrollbar is at the left, but I need it to automatically align with the current date whenever the view loads for the first time.

If anyone has tackled a similar issue or knows of any properties or methods that could be used to achieve this, your insights would be greatly appreciated. I am looking for any possible workaround or script that could manipulate the scrollbar position dynamically based on the system's current time.

My earlier answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66619545/5947043 is relevant to this I think. I haven't found a way around the limitation.
